# What's a good way to structure code that needs to "patch" behavior of some other class?

Tags: class-design

I'm trying to implement parts of the ASME BPVC's design rules. It's a very, very old code that has been grown over a hundred years or so. As such, it covers lots of different load cases, lots of different component configurations, and has different paths depending on the presence of certain design criteria. Most things are dead-simple mathematical procedures, but every step needs to be shown to the end user so that they can verify the calculations.

Many parts of the design code are procedural design requirements, such as "procedure 10: Do X, then Y, in order to determine Z" where Y depends on X, and Z depends on Y. Later on, a subsection will read "For procedure 10 with cyclic loading, use gamma* instead of gamma to calculate Y*, and substitute Y* for Y when calculating Z"

The above scenario is a simplified situation - in some cases, it whacks off part of an equation and substitutes a new one if certain design conditions are present and substitutes new values in other equations.

I'm trying to encapsulate these equations into their own classes to create only a single point of change, because the time between new rules being released and the time tested code needs to be in place is about 3 months. Since coding is not my full time job, this application needs to be very maintainable and easily modifiable.

Currently, the main analysis is stored in a class. Code that patches its behavior is a subclass. But I ran into an issue where two different subsections can modify one another as well as the main class, so the two classes would be on the same level in the hierarchy of things.

Any advice on how to structure this? Language isn't important, only speed and accuracy.

Comment: If you have some spare time for a book, pick up 'Working Effectively with Legacy Code' from Michael Feathers.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe sounds like a use case for [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This approach allows you to separate the different procedures into separate pieces of code (methods or opbjects), and apply one or another depending on the situation. The dependencies between different stages might be handled by [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).